# small extension of MVT

Tags: calculus

f is cts on all of [a,b]& differentiable on most [a,b] EXCEPT at finitely many points where f is vertical because f’ is positive infinity. (left and right limits match)

Can you still *always* find c in [a,b] so f’(c) = (f(b)-f(a))/(b-a)?

What is a counter example?

Here is an example that does not prove anything.

[image: a graph of the cube root on -1 to 1]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure. WLOG, assume that $f(a) = f(b)$ and that $f$ attains its maximum in $(a, b)$. Then take some $c \in (a, b)$ which maximises $f(c)$. Then $c$ is a critical point, so either $f'(c) = \infty$ or $f'(c) = 0$. But clearly, it cannot be that $f'(c) = \infty$, since then we could find some $\epsilon$ such that $f(c + \epsilon) > f(c)$. So $f'(c) = 0$.